# How to map value at index 0 for a list in an Optional Stream

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following method which is working fine. I am trying to accomplish everything and get the value inside that Optional stream 
without having to do the additional if check. Is it possible to map and get the Result object at index 0? Please advice thanks.

```
public String getData(HttpEntity<Request> request, String endPoint){
    ResponseEntity<Reponse> response = 
        template.exchange(endPoint, HttpMethod.POST, request, Reponse.class);

    List<Result> results = Optional.ofNullable(response)
        .map(ResponseEntity::getBody)
        .map(Response::getQueryResult)
        .map(QueryResult::getResults)
        // getResults is an ArrayList of Result Objects. Could I get the Result Object at index 0 here? 
        // following that I plan to go .map(Result::getValue) here. 
        .orElse(null);
    if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(results)){
        return results.get(0).getValue();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return Optional.ofNullable(response)
               .map(ResponseEntity::getBody)
               .map(Response::getQueryResult)
               .map(QueryResult::getResults)
               .filter(CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty)
               .map(list -> list.get(0)) // hate this part :)
               .map(Result::getValue)
               .orElse(null);
```

If you are a fan of method references, and you find lambdas boring

```
return Optional.ofNullable(response)
               .map(ResponseEntity::getBody)
               .map(Response::getQueryResult)
               .map(QueryResult::getResults)
               .filter(CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty)
               .map(List::iterator)
               .map(Iterator::next)
               .map(Result::getValue)
               .orElse(null);
```

I showed it for educational reasons,  I don't advocate it even though I like it.

Comment: I actually like the method reference better. Question. Why the need to check if collection is empty? Since it is Optional of nullable I would just end up returning null right even without that check?

Comment: @karvai the following method `list.get(0)` or `list.iterator().next()` would try to access the first element which could cause an exception (particularly, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`)

Comment: I wouldn’t be surprised if nothing of this chain can ever be `null` and a simple straight-forward `return response.getBody().getQueryResult().getResults().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);` would do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `ArrayList` is never `null`:

```
.flatMap(r -> r.stream().findFirst())
```

This takes the list, streams it, gets an `Optional` with the first element (or an empty `Optional` if the list is empty. Lastly, since an `Optional<Optional<Result>>` isn't that useful, we use `flatMap` instead of `map` to collapse it into an `Optional<Result>`.

Answer (score 2):

change that `orElse` to return an `empty` List and `stream` from there. In such a way you can invoke `findFirst` safely - as for an empty List it will return `Optional::empty` and from there - you either map it (in case you do have it) to `Result::getValue` or, in case such a List is not present - `null`, so it is exactly as your program flow.

```
...
   .map(QueryResult::getResults)
   .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
   .stream()
   .findFirst()
   .map(Result::getValue)
   .orElse(null);
```